# Get emacs to read unquoted strings in json

Tags: string, json

I am trying to use emacs-lisp to interact with a MongoDB. Here is an example of a string that mongo returns, that emacs cannot read. The problem is the unquoted ObjectId and ISODate items (if I put quotes around them, then it parses fine).

```
(json-read-from-string "[ { \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"589f59860a25be50ecd9a6d0\"), \"date-added\" : ISODate(\"2017-02-11T18:35:50.046Z\") }, { \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"589f598c0a25be50ecd9a6d1\"), \"date-added\" : ISODate(\"2017-02-11T18:35:56.634Z\") } ]")
```

Is there a way to get the json library to read this kind of json? Right now what I do is "quote" and "dequote" the json string, but it means I have to keep it up to date with all the things that mongo might return one day.

Comment: Maybe you could add add entries for upper case letters into `json-readtable`.

Comment: That is an interesting idea. I will look into that. Thanks.

Comment: Well... this isn't JSON really. It's JavaScript. Why not try using Node.js for this?

Comment: How would you do that through emacs? I have a comint-mode that sends queries to mongo as json, and it sends back what it calls json, except it has those things in it.